# Python ctypes integer pointer

Tags: python, ctypes

How can i implement this function using python ctypes

```
extern  int __stdcall GetRate(HANDLE hDev, int* pData)
```

How to set datatypes so that i can print pData value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to call a function named `GetRate`, you can do it as:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

GetRate = windll.YOURLIB.GetRate
GetRate.restype = c_int
GetRate.argtypes = [HANDLE, POINTER(c_int)]

# now call GetRate as something like:
#
# hDev = ... # handle
# Data = c_int()
#
# GetRate(hDev, byref(Data)) # GetRate(hDev, &Data)
# print Data
```

but if you try to declare a callback, function pointer, you can do it as (I think you're looking for the first):

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

def GetRate(hDev, pDate):
    # Your implementation
    return 0

# you'll need GETRATE to pass it in the argtypes to the target function
GETRATE = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, HANDLE, POINTER(c_int))
pGetRate = GETRATE(GetRate)

# now you can pass pGetRate as a callback to another function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i was looking for the first but when i print data the reply is like this `c_long(104)` why its not printing actual value

Comment: @ganeshredcobra I'm not sure where that came from, but `c_long(104)` is an object and you can print its content as `c_int(104).value`.

Comment: @ganeshredcobra: `c_int` is `c_long` on 32-bit platforms or Win64,  but it's inconceivable that you're getting a ctypes data type as a result. The simple types have getters that return Python objects as a `restype`.